# Getting the caller to a Spring AOP Proxy

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aop

I'm searching for a way of developing a MethodInterceptor which prints the caller class.

Is there any way of getting the caller object into the method interceptor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work, declare an exception and then use it to get a look at the stack at the time when your method is intercepted:

```
Throwable t = new Throwable();
StackTraceElement[] elements = t.getStackTrace();

String calleeMethod = elements[0].getMethodName();
String callerMethodName = elements[1].getMethodName();
String callerClassName = elements[1].getClassName();

System.out.println("CallerClassName=" + callerClassName + " , Caller method name: " + callerMethodName);
System.out.println("Callee method name: " + calleeMethod);
```

Comment: This will get the class name. Is there a way to get the calling instance, so that my advice can visit the calling instance?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something crude with generating a stack trace and inspecting it, but that is ugly